# Windows 7 Unchangable AppLocker Rules

Tags: security, windows-7, applocker

I have a windows 7 image that appears to be using an applocker ruleset that I'm unable to modify or disable.

Performing the following appears to have no effect on this enforced AppLocker mystery ruleset:

- Disabling the AppIdSvc
- restarting the AppIdSvc
- updating the AppLocker ruleset in the local security policy (this system is not part of the domain)
- Any combination of the above

The above comes from this [technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh310286(v=WS.10).aspx).

This is the result of using the applocker powershell module:

```
Import-Module AppLocker
Get-AppLockerPolicy -Effective | Test-AppLockerPolicy -Path c:\TestScript.bat

FilePath                             PolicyDecision MatchingRule
--------                             -------------- ------------
C:\TestScript.bat                  AllowedByDefault
```

If I create a wildcard ruleset for scripts or exes, this test changes to Allowed for the policydecision.

However, when actually testing execution, I receive the error `This program is blocked by group policy...` and there's a corresponding message in the AppLocker event log stating the execution was prevented from running with a blank RuleName and zeroed RuleId.

There also appears to be rules in effect.  If I ran the TestScript.bat as an administrator (UAC is on) then the script will execute as expected an an event will be registered stating the execution was allowed with a RuleName of All scripts.  This rule likely came from an earlier setup but I can't seem to find it or remove it.  how can I remove these hidden rules?

Answer (score 1):

I found a partial solution.  The AppLocker rules that were in effect but hidden from the security policy (secpol.msc or gpedit.msc) where located here:

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Srp\Gp
```

From here I was able to manually manipulate the applocker rules.  However, I'm still unable to modify these rules through the security policy or the Set-AppLockerPolicy cmdlet.  Something is preventing the system from applying the AppLocker rules.